# Investigating $\sum \prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I'm investigating the behavior of the following function as $x\to \infty$:
$$f(x):=\sum_{1\le n\le x}\frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}$$
where $J_k(n)$ is the Jordan's totient function
$$J_k(n):=n^k\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac1{p^k})$$
and I found that

> $$f(x)=\frac x{\zeta (2)}(\ln x+2\gamma-1)+O(\sqrt x)$$

*Here's my work:*

Since
$$\sum_{d\mid n}J_2(n)=n^2$$
The Möbius inversion formula gives
$$J_2(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d) \left(\frac nd\right)^2\ \ 
\implies\ \ \frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n\le x}\frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}=\sum_{d\le x}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}\sum_{n\le x,d\mid n}1$$
From p44 in the [book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=UEk-CgAAQBAJ&dq=dirichlet+hyperbola+method&pg=PR15&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=dirichlet%20hyperbola%20method&f=false), the Dirichlet hyperbola method gives
$$\sum_{n\le x,d\mid n}1=x(\ln x+2\gamma -1) +O(\sqrt x)$$
and since
$$\sum_{d\ge 1}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}=\frac 1{\zeta(2)}$$
we get the result.

However, when I plot the graph of
$$g(x):=\frac{\zeta(2)f(x)-x\ln x}{(2\gamma-1)x}$$
with Mathematica, $g$ doesn't tend to $1$ as $x\to\infty$:

[image: graph]

Where did I do wrong?

[Mathematica code for Jordan's totient function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116540/how-can-i-implement-jordans-totient-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should plug in

$$
\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\d|n}}1=\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor=\frac xd+O(1)
$$

instead of the asymptotic formula for the sum over divisor function. This indicates the correct asymptotic expansion should be

$$
\sum_{n\le x}{J_2(n)\over n^2}=x\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^3}+O\left(\sum_{d\ge1}{1\over d^2}\right)={x\over\zeta(3)}+O(1).
$$

Comment: $\sum 1=\sum(\frac xd +O(1))$, so the error term should be $O(x)$ instead?

Comment: @Tianlalu No, the series actually converges

Comment: Many thanks for your help!