# Best bound for $|\sum \prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^k})-\frac m{\zeta(k+1)}|$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

Follow from the [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4424462/394456), we have

\begin{align*}
f_2(x):=\sum_{n\le x} \prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})-\frac x{\zeta(3)}=O(1)\quad \text{as }x\to\infty.\tag{*}
\end{align*}
When I tried to plot $f_2$, I observed that for any $m\in \Bbb N,$
$$|f_2(m)|=\left|\sum_{n\le m}\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})-\frac m{\zeta(3)}\right|< c\approx0.22,$$
In particular, $0<f_2(m)<\color{red}{0.222656...}$. Here is the plot for $m\le 10000$:

[image: f2]

I have no idea how to estimate $c\approx0.22$ through analytical method.

- **Is it possible to find the exact value of $c$?**
- **If not, could we prove the less tight case (e.g. $|f_2|<0.3$)?**

> Since for any $\ell\ge2$,
> \begin{align*}
> f_\ell(x):=\sum_{n\le x} \prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^\ell})-\frac x{\zeta(\ell+1)}=O(1)\quad \text{as }x\to\infty.\tag{**}
> \end{align*}
> One may generalize the question to finding the smallest $c_\ell$ such that
> $$|f_\ell(m)|=\left|\sum_{n\le m}\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^\ell})-\frac m{\zeta(\ell+1)}\right|< c_\ell,\quad \forall m\in\Bbb N.$$

---

**Update**

Follow Gary's comment, if we define
\begin{align*}
F_2(x):=\frac1x\sum_{n\le x} f_2(n)
\end{align*}
The graph is

[image: F2]

Mathematica code:

```
jordanTotient[n_, k_: 1] := 
DivisorSum[n, #^k*MoebiusMu[n/#] &] /; (n > 0) && IntegerQ[n];
Plot[1/x Sum[(Sum[jordanTotient[n, 2]/n^2, {n, 1, m}] - 
 m/Zeta[3]), {m, 1, Floor[x]}], {x, 0, 100}]
```

---

**Update 2**

We look at the corresponding Dirichlet series and make use of Perron's formula to get the asymptotic.
\begin{align*}
f(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})=\frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}\quad \implies \quad
F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{J_2(n)}{n^{s+2}}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}.
\end{align*}

Where $J_k(\cdot)$ is the Jordan totient function. Now making use of Perron's formula,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}=\frac12\frac{J_2(m)}{m^2}+\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s\,\mathrm ds\tag{***}
\end{align*}
for any $c>1$. The integrand $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s$ has poles at $s=0$ and $s=1$.

We shift the line of integration to the left across the pole $s=1$. Let $b\in (0,1)$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s\,\mathrm ds=&\underbrace{\text{Res}\left(\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s,1\right)}_{=m/\zeta(3)}+
\underbrace{\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{b-iT}^{b+iT}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s\,\mathrm ds}_{\text{vertical integral}}\\
&+ \underbrace{\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{b-iT}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s\,\mathrm ds+\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{b+iT}^{c+iT}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+2)}\frac{m^s}s\,\mathrm ds}_{\text{horizontal integral}}.
\end{align*}

Thus,
$$f_2(m)=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{J_2(n)}{n^2}-\frac{m}{\zeta(3)}=\frac12\frac{J_2(m)}{m^2}+\color{red}{O(?)}$$
but I do not know how to estimate these integrals to get $O(?)$.

I am not sure if the above steps are correct as I am new on this topic. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{x}{\zeta(3)}$ instead of $\frac{x}{\zeta(2)}$?

Comment: @Gary typo fixed.

Comment: What graph would you get for the summatory function $$
F_2 (x): = \frac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{m \le x} {\left( {f_2 (m) - \frac{m}{{\zeta (3)}}} \right)} \,?
$$

Comment: Do you mean the following instead? $$F_2(x):=\frac1x\sum_{n\le x} \bigg(\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p^2})-\frac n{\zeta(3)}\bigg)$$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $$
F_2 (x) := \frac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{n \le x} {f_2 (n)} .
$$

Comment: Are you sure about that graph? Since $|f_2(n)|<c$, $|F_2(x)|<\frac{1}{x}\cdot cx=c$.

Comment: @Gary The graph should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let

$$
g_\ell(n)=\prod_{p|n}\left(1-{1\over p^\ell}\right),
$$

so that it follows from the Dirichlet convolution property

$$
g_\ell(n)=\sum_{d|n}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}
$$

that

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\le x}g_\ell(n)
&=\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor=x\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^{\ell+1}}-\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}\left\{\frac xd\right\} \\
&={x\over\zeta(\ell+1)}-x\sum_{d>x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}-\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}\left\{\frac xd\right\}.
\end{aligned}

This suggests that the key ingredients in the estimation of $f_\ell(m)$ are as follows:

$$
|f_\ell(x)|\le x|S_1(x)|+|S_2(x)|.
$$

where

$$
S_1(x)=\sum_{d>x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell},\quad S_2(x)=\sum_{n\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}\left\{\frac xd\right\}.
$$

### Estimation of $S_1(x)$

The prime number theorem in the form of de la Vallée Poussin implies that there exists an constant $c_0>0$ such that

$$
M(x)=\sum_{n\le x}\mu(n)=O\left\{x\exp\left(-c_0\sqrt{\log x}\right)\right\}
$$

This indicates that

$$
\sum_{d>x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}=\int_x^\infty{\mathrm dM(t)\over t^\ell}=-{M(x)\over x^\ell}+\ell\int_x^\infty{M(t)\over t^{\ell+1}}\mathrm dt=O\left\{x^{1-\ell}\exp\left(-c_0\sqrt{\log x}\right)\right\}
$$

If $\ell\ge2$ then $x|S_1(x)|$ will certainly vanish at infinity. This suggests that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $x_0=x_0(\varepsilon)$ such that for all $x>x_0$ there is

$$
|f_\ell(x)|<|S_2(x)|+\varepsilon
$$

Thus, the remaining task is to handle $S_2(x)$.

### Preliminary treatments for $S_2(x)$

\begin{aligned}
S_2(x)
&=\frac12\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)\over d^\ell}+S_3(x) \\
&={1\over2\zeta(\ell)}+O\left\{x^{1-\ell}\exp\left(-c_0\sqrt{\log x}\right)\right\}+S_3(x)
\end{aligned}

where

$$
S_3(x)=\sum_{d\le x}{1\over d^\ell}\overline B_1\left(\frac xd\right)
$$

and $\overline B_n(x)$ denotes the periodized Bernoulli polynomials. I guess tricks from the theory of trigonometric sums/integral should come in handy to handle $S_3(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to get a tighter bound of $|f_\ell|$ (e.g. $|f_2(m)|<0.3$ for any $m\in\Bbb N$)?

Comment: @Tianlalu I have just edited the answer. I guess $1/2\zeta(\ell)$ is likely the best possible estimate obtained via this appraoch.

Comment: Sorry but it seems $M(x)=O(x)$ also works in your steps, why we choose that tighter bound? Also, could you give more details about estimating $S_3$ (as I'm not familiar with it)? Thank you.

Comment: No, the trivial bound won’t be helpful to estimate $S_1$ if $\ell=2$. I’ll update stuff on $S_3$ tomorrow

Comment: This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2792.pdf) states $$\sum_{d\le x}{\mu(d)}\left\{\frac xd\right\}=-1+O(x\log^{-2}x).$$Does it imply $S_2=O(x^{1-\ell})$?

Comment: @Tianlalu I indeed wish $S_2\to0$, but I think there are still more efforts needed to convert the result of that paper to something we can use.

Comment: Could we use the similar trick as in lemma 3.4？

Comment: @Tianlalu then all you get is $O(1)$, a pretty trivial result.

Comment: @Tianlalu but thanks for that interesting paper tho